# pip3 install requests for Python3, but still not module named 'requests'

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, pip

I used `pip3 install requests` to install `request` for `Python3`
This is the output:

```
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.13.0
```

But when I tried to import `requests` in `Python3`, an error throwed

```
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

The outputs for `pip3 -V` :

```
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

The outputs for `Python3 -V` : `Python 3.5.1`

Comment: Output of `pip3 show requests | grep "Location:"`? How about `python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"`?
Is it possible you have multiple python3's installed?

Comment: @lemonhead. No output of `pip3 show requests | grep "Location:"`. The output of `python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"` :  `['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']`

Comment: Hmm... hard to say but it sounds like requests didn't install correctly.  If you do `pip uninstall requests` it should prompt you with all the files it installed to delete.  Verify that they actually landed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/pytho‌​n3.5/site-packages`.

Comment: also is this python3 or Python3?

Comment: @lemonhead. It shows `Cannot uninstall requirement requests, not installed` on both `pip uninstall requests` and `pip3 uninstall requests`. They are not inside in path you said. What do you mean python3 and Python3?

Comment: hmm.... out of ideas then.  Try re-running `pip3 install requests`? Or try specifying the python explicitly this time -- e.g. `pip3 -p $(which Python3) install requests`

Comment: @lemonhead. Re-run this installation just shows the same output as first installation. And `pip3 -p $(which Python3) install requests` gives an error `Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

no such option: -p`